# Why can some arrays be published but not others?

Tags: delphi, arrays, properties, delphi-2009

```
type
   TStaticArray = array[1..10] of integer;
   TDynamicArray = array of integer;

   TMyClass = class(TObject)
   private
      FStaticArray: TStaticArray;
      FDynamicArray: TDynamicArray;
   published
      property staticArray: TStaticArray read FStaticArray write FStaticArray; //compiler chokes on this
      property dynamicArray: TDynamicArray read FDynamicArray write FDynamicArray; //compiler accepts this one just fine
   end;
```

What's going on here?  A static array gives the error, "published property 'staticArray' cannot be of type ARRAY" but dynamic arrays are just fine?  I'm confused.  Anyone know the reasoning behind this, and how I can work around it?  (And no, I don't want to redeclare all my static arrays as dynamic.  They're the size they are for a reason.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Published declaration tells the compiler to store information in the virtual method table. Only certain kinds of information can be stored.
The type of a published property cannot be a pointer, record, or array. If it is a set type, it must be small enough to be stored in an integer.
(O'REILLY, DELPHİ IN A NUTSHELL)

Comment: Just one precision: a record can't be used as a published property. Or in fact, it is allowed, but there is no RTTI attached to this field. So it will be useless to add a record in a published section of properties. Whereas a dynamic array is allowed and handled within the RTTI.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have getters and setters. Under D2009 (didn't check other versions), the parameters to the getters/setters can't, for some reason, be const. ?

This works fine under D2009:

```
type
  TMyArray = array[0..20] of string;

type
  TMyClass=class(TObject)
  private
    FMyArray: TMyArray;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): String;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: string);
  public
    property Items[Index: Integer]: string read GetItem write SetItem;
  end;

implementation

function TMyClass.GetItem(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (Index > -1) and (Index < Length(FMyArray)) then
    Result := FMyArray[Index];
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: string);
begin
  if (Index > -1) and (Index < Length(FMyArray)) then
    FMyArray[Index] := Value;
end;
```

NOTE: I would not typically just ignore Index values out of range, obviously. This was a quick example of how to make static array properties in a class definition; IOW, it's a compilable example only.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can publish a dynamic array property, is that dynamic arrays is implemented as references, or 'implicitly pointer'. They work more like strings, really.

The reason why you can't publish a static array, I don't know. It's just the way it's made, I guess..

For more details on how dynamic arrays work, take a look at [DrBobs site](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi4/dynarray.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
 TMyClass = class(TObject)
   private
     FStaticArray: TStaticArray;
     FIdx: Integer;
     function  GetFoo(Index: Integer): Integer;
     procedure SetFoo(Index: Integer; Value: Integer);
   public
     property Foo[Index: Integer] : Integer read GetFoo write SetFoo;
   published
     property Idx: Integer read fidx write fidx;
     property AFoo: Integer read GetAFoo writte SetAFoo;
   end;
implementation
function TMyClass.GetAFoo: Integer;
begin
  result := FStaticArray[FIdx];
end;
procedure TMyClass.SetAFoo(Value: Integer);
begin
  FStaticArray[FIdx] := Value;
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly tell us anything about the *WHY*.

Answer (score -3):

Array properties cannot be published.
So the following code does not work. The work around probably is to make it `public`.

```
   TMyClass = class(TObject)
   private
     FStaticArray: TStaticArray;

     function  GetFoo(Index: Integer): Integer;
     procedure SetFoo(Index: Integer; Value: Integer);
   public
     property Foo[Index: Integer] : Integer read GetFoo write SetFoo;
   end;
```

Comment: How can you get the same error without using TStaticArray as property?

Comment: Because it's still an array property.  And I downvoted that for a reason Gortok: it's a demonstrably incorrect answer.  (Plug that in and it won't compile.)

Comment: Mason's right. You cant publish array properties. That's just the way it works...

Comment: Your example is wrong, because you still left the array property in the published section, rather than making it public (which would work). Please edit to correct, and I won't downvote. :-)